# Report Builder 3.0 does not open report model

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0

When I choose 'Edit in Report Builder' on a report on the report server, in Report Builder 1.0 it opens the report in a report model design view with the available Entities and Fields on the left-hand side, like so:

[image: Report Builder 1.0]

But when I do the same in Report Builder 3.0, it opens the report in a standard design view (as in Visual Studio), like so:

[image: Report Builder 3.0]

How do I make it so that Report Builder 3.0 opens the report in the same way that Report Builder 1.0 does?

Comment: Right click on the `dataset`, click `dataset properties`, then click `Query Designer...`

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thanks, that worked!